# Ubuntu Server 20.10 - virtual interfaces in netplan

Tags: networking, netplan, interface

I am trying to add a virtual interface to a bare metal Ubuntu Server 20.10 installation.

I've read that in pre version 20 this wasn't possible in netplan, and that people were reverting to ifup/ifdown. But this is supposed to be possible with what I have.

I am trying to give my server a second interface so I can bind a pihole docker container to said interface.

I see in the netplan docs various interface types, and the closest one is a vlan type, but it doesn't seem that type works with untagged vlans.

In any case, I appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to assume that by "virtual interface" you mean that you want to have a main interface (Example: "eth0"), which may or may not have an address on one subnet, and you want to create an interface labeled differently (Example: "eth0:0") with an address on a different subnet.

Prior to netplan version 0.100, this was not supported.  However, version 0.100 added the **lifetime** and **label** properties to the **addresses** values.

You can check your installed netplan version with the following command: `dpkg -l | grep netplan`

Here is an example .yaml that will attempt to use dhcp to assign an IP address to the *eth0* interface, and will assign the static IP address *192.168.55.151/24* to the virtual interface labeled *eth0:0*:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp6: no
      dhcp4: yes
      optional: true
      addresses: 
        - 192.168.55.151/24: 
            lifetime: 0
            label: "eth0:0"
```

This will produce the following results (of course *eth0* would have an IP if it were connected to a DHCP server):

```
odroid@odroid:~$ ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::21e:6ff:fe48:114  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:1e:06:48:01:14  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 6389  bytes 966018 (966.0 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 1649  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 531  bytes 160364 (160.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 21  

eth0:0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.55.151  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.55.255
        ether 00:1e:06:48:01:14  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        device interrupt 21  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 31816  bytes 2259360 (2.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 31816  bytes 2259360 (2.2 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

odroid@odroid:~$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:1e:06:48:01:14 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.55.151/24 brd 192.168.55.255 scope global deprecated eth0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::21e:6ff:fe48:114/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Seems to have been deprecated on netplan 0.104. Does not create eth0:0

Answer (score 1):

"Virtual interface" can refer to a variety of different technologies.  Normally, containers are attached to a bridge.  You can create bridges in netplan, using syntax such as:

```
network:
  version: 2
  bridges:
    dockernet:
      addresses: [10.1.1.1/24]
```

Comment: I mean a something similar to a macvlan interface, you'd typically attach it to the parent interface via a bridge, but it would have its own IP address as well as its own unique MAC address.

Answer (score 1):

Update to edited question.

Netplan can assign multiple addresses to a single interface and does not support interface aliases (e.g. eth0:0).

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
    ethernets:
        enp3s0:
         addresses:
             - 10.100.1.38/24
             - 10.100.1.39/24
         gateway4: 10.100.1.1
```

Taken from this link https://netplan.io/examples/#using-multiple-addresses-on-a-single-interface

Docker try's to bind to all interfaces by default. An ip address on a given interface can by specified.
`docker run -d -p 10.0.0.1:8080:80 nginx`

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar but on the docker host itself. the docker macvlan driver/implementation has some nuances I am trying to work around. Namely that the host system cannot access a docker containers services if said container is using a macvlan interface.

the docker image I am using specifically is pihole, and I'd like the host to be able to use it as a recursive DNS server.

Comment: You can bind to localhost with or without external port this example is with external port 8080  `docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:8080:80 nginx`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do the job: https://netplan.io/examples/#attaching-vlans-to-network-interfaces

```
network:
version: 2
renderer: networkd
ethernets:
    mainif:
        match:
            macaddress: "de:ad:be:ef:ca:fe"
        set-name: mainif
        addresses: [ "10.3.0.5/23" ]
        gateway4: 10.3.0.1
        nameservers:
            addresses: [ "8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4" ]
            search: [ example.com ]
vlans:
    vlan15:
        id: 15
        link: mainif
        addresses: [ "10.3.99.5/24" ]
    vlan10:
        id: 10
        link: mainif
        addresses: [ "10.3.98.5/24" ]
        nameservers:
            addresses: [ "127.0.0.1" ]
            search: [ domain1.example.com, domain2.example.com ]
```